# WP8 - Change Panorama title font size (template editing)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I am a newbie at Windows Phone 8 developing.

As long as it may look like a silly question, I read around how to change the font size of the panorama title and actually failed at getting it done on my new project.

They all say to just apply this template, modifying the standard one:

```
 <application.resources>
                <datatemplate x:key="SmallPanoramaTitle">
                    <contentpresenter>
                        <textblock text="{Binding}" fontsize="50" margin="0,70,0,0" />
                    </contentpresenter>
                </datatemplate>
    </application.resources>
```

How can I actually do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a blog post detailing how to change the default template for the Panorama control: [Changing the background for panorama title and panorama header](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/changing-the-background-for-panorama-title-and-panorama-header/).

Did you apply the template from your post to the target panorama control? You can do that with the following code:

```
<Panorama TitleTemplate="{StaticResource SmallPanoramaTitle}">
```

Comment: as silly as it may look, I actually don't know where the templates are located at all.
Am I required to create a new file? Do I have to write the template code in any other specific file?

Comment: I basically don't know where I should paste the code I put there, at all :(

Comment: You can write templates in the same file where the control is. You just need to put it in the `phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources` block.

Comment: Tbh I can't really understand how to apply the template, once I have written it into App.xaml

Comment: If I use <Panorama TitleTemplate="{StaticTemplate SmallPanoramaTitle}">, all I get is: "the name StaticTemplate does not exist in the current namespace"

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT! (sorry for caps, but I am that happy!)

Changed StaticTemplate with StaticResource and I got it fixed :)

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I wrote it out of my head :/ Glad you managed to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

if your actual question was "where to put this template"? it should be in App.xaml as it contains `Application.Resources` tag which belongs to App.xaml :

```
<Application ...>
    ....
    <Application.Resources>
        ....
        <!-- Other resources if any -->
        ....
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallPanoramaTitle">
            <ContentPresenter>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" Margin="0,70,0,0" />
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
    ....
</Application>
```

After that you can use the template in the way shown by @ToniPetrina.

Comment: I already tried doing that, tbh. All I am getting is "The name "datatemplate" does not exist in the namespace" :|

(same for "contentpresenter" and "textblock")

Comment: it's all about wrong case used, `datatemplate` should be `DataTemplate`, etc. You could try again, I have fixed it.

Comment: Cheers! Didn't notice that!

What I am missing now is the "application" of the template to the Panorama, I don't get how I should use this string:

<Panorama TitleTemplate="{StaticTemplate SmallPanoramaTitle}">

This is my panorama string right now:

<phone:Panorama HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="723" Margin="-4,10,0,0" Title="Wolfram Alpha" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />

How should it become, given that the template name is <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallPanoramaTitle"> ?